Why can the curvature form of line bundle be nonzero in de Rham cohomology
Let $L$ be a line bundle on $M$, I take the definition from Griffith&Harris that the curvature form of $L$ is the curvature 2-form $\Theta$ on $M$ defined by ANY connection $D$. let $\theta$ be the connection 1-form of $D$ under any chosen frame, the curvature is the 2-form $\Theta_D=d\theta$, which should have a class $0$ in de Rham cohomology. But it's known that the chern class $c_1(L)=[i\Theta_D/(2\pi)]$, which shouldn't be all 0. Where am I getting wrong?

The curvature is not just the exterior derivative of $\theta$ but rather the exterior covariant derivative, which in general does not square to $0$. The curvature precisely measures the failure of the exterior covariant derivative squaring to $0$.

@NicoZimmer  Hi, Nico, could you elaborate a bit more on "exterior covariant derivative"? I know that in general case the curvature is $\Theta=d\theta -\theta\wedge\theta$, and I'm saying the curvature is $d\theta$ in line bundle case because $\theta$ is a 1*1 matrix, thus a 1-form.

@L H.R First of all, I suppose you mean $D$ is a connection on the line bundle $L$ (technically $L\to M$). Unless your bundle is trivial, you only have $\Theta=\mathrm d \theta$ locally, which at most shows that $\Theta$ is closed. For $\Theta$ to be exact you would need $\Theta=\mathrm d \theta$ globally.

Elaborating my comments a bit further:
What you have is a connection $D$ on the line bundle $L\to M$. In terms of a local frame $e\colon U\to L$, $D$ is given by a local one-form $\theta$ so that on $U$
$$
\Theta=\mathrm d\theta-\theta\wedge\theta=\mathrm d \theta.
$$
Unless you have a global frame of $L$ (i.e. unless the bundle is trivial), however, this relation only holds locally (as in the above case only on the domain of the local frame) so that you generically cannot conclude the exactness of $\Theta$ from this local relation.

I see,  I was forgetting that $\theta$ is not a global form! Thanks for the clarification!

Just to emphasize the point, given any closed $2$-form $\omega$, the equation $\mathrm{d}\alpha = \omega$ for the unknown $1$-form $\alpha$ always admits local solutions by the Poincaré lemma applied to coordinate charts, and the de Rham cohomology class $[\omega]$ is the cohomological obstruction to the existence of a global solution.
